# Spring adds application.properties with valiues from external properties to classpath, and how to disable it?

Tags: java, spring

### The question(?)

I've made the application properties external because of the database configuration and API keys but through some `spring magic` they get read and only spring valiues are left and placed into the classpath, overriding the external properties later on deployment. So how would I disable this "feature", so that it wont include the properties inside the jar?

#### The code I used to make the properties external

```java
@Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties =
                new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        properties.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("program.properties"));
        properties.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(false);
        return properties;
    }
```

I have a suspition that the placeholder part of PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer has the difrence, but my nonnative English research skills couldn't find any results.

#### Edits

- It is packaged as a jar with bundled tomcat
- Properties file is located in the home dir of the jar

Comment: In your project's folder, where is your properties file located? There is any chance that it's being packaged in your jar/war ?

Comment: Updated the post with info

Comment: Quick test: remove manually the properties file from inside your jar, then try running your code. It should read your external file, or throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

*Ive found the solution.*

### Introduction

Spring compiles the properties inside the file if you use the code snippet most commonly provided with the question `"How to make application.properties external?"`. Its probably intentional misleading but lets not get contraversial.

### The solution

First edit the code that you use to configure spring as this is the right solution (atleast for me)

```java
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Application.class);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(new FileReader("application.properties"));
            application.setDefaultProperties(properties);
            application.run(args);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Second you need to edit the maven configuration to not include the file

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <addResources>false</addResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

***And if that doesnt work check the target directory if application.properties is still left there.***

Hopefully this will be useful for people that had the same headache as me. :)